# Show Progress bar or spinner when ajax is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am trying to add a progress bar or a spinner when the ajax is running, but the progress bar and spinner will only appear at same time with the success alert from ajax.

Note: I am using JSP and the ajax is used to update the database data through servlet. The progress bar is using bootstrap.

```
    $('#sync').click(function () {

        var start = $('#startdate').val();

        var end = $('#enddate').val();

        if ((start !== "") && (end !== "")) {

            var startDate = new Date(start);

            var endDate = new Date(end);

            $('#cover').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "PRSync",
                data: "start=" + startDate.yyyymmdd() +
                        "&end=" + endDate.yyyymmdd(),
                async: false,
                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var arr = data.split('|');
                    if (arr[0] === "0") {
                        alert("Sync fail");
                    } else {
                        alert("Sync Succesfull. Total rows of " + arr[1] + " affected.");
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, err4) { // if error occured
                    alert(jqXHR + " _ " + textStatus + " _ " + errorThrown + " _ " + err4);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#cover').fadeOut(1000);
                }
            });

        }
    });
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        // show loader on start
        showbusy();
    }).ajaxSuccess(function () {
        // hide loader on success
        hidebusy();
    });


    Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function () {
        var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
        var mm = (this.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
        var dd = this.getDate().toString();
        return yyyy + "-" + (mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + "-" + (dd[1] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]); // padding
    };

    var myApp;
    myApp = myApp || (function () {
        var pleaseWaitDiv = $('<div class="modal fade" style=top:40% id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="false"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">Synchronizing is processing</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%"></div></div></div></div></div></div>');
        return {
            showPleaseWait: function () {
                pleaseWaitDiv.modal();
            },
            hidePleaseWait: function () {
                pleaseWaitDiv.modal('hide');
            },
        };
    })();
    function showbusy() {
        myApp.showPleaseWait();
    }
    function hidebusy() {
        myApp.hidePleaseWait();
    }
```

Comment: Here is a good blog that can help you on the way. http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/

Comment: You could assume that if both start & end are not empty the AJAX will start? Well, why don't you append in that statement a spinner to your DOM, and hide it again on success?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxStart", function(){
    showbusy(); })
.bind("ajaxStop", function(){
    hidebusy();
});
```

Obviously, if your ajax call is processed very fast, it might seem that your function is triggered 'to late', however by binding the events to `$(document)` you make sure that they are not triggered once only.

If that still does not suite your needs, I would place the functions inside the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     beforeSend: showbusy(),
     complete: hidebusy()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jquery.blockUI.js](http://malsup.com/jquery/block).

You can initialize it like this in your code:

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```